# Need answer should be Need answers to match tab text

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav, plurals

- Click on new it says New questions
- Click on popular it says Popular questions
- Click on need answers it says Need answer

An additional s would be nice for consistency with the other need answers occurrences.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed, and is currently in production.

---

Will fix!

Obligatory reference:

[image: Pluralization]

Answer (score 2):

Yes!!! Fix it, fix it, fix it!!!

This is a serious problem here. The title should at least match with its respective tab here. All questions need answers, yes more than one. If questions only needed one answer, I won't be able to post this answer because there was another one before me. Or maybe every answer will become `Community Wiki`...

This shouldn't be hard to fix. So fix it please for the sake of completeness. :)

Answer (score -5):

But the person needs *only one* answer.

Comment: And if you're referring to all questions? There won't be a single question in that tab...

Comment: What am I going to do now? I've got more than one answer. Can I donate this one to charity or something?

Comment: Accept my answer to make it the "official answer". :)

Comment: ...or accept the **real** official answer :P

Comment: Why so many negative votes? o.O